# How to translate "The difference between the impossible and possible lies in a person's determination"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would you translate this quote?

> The difference between the impossible and possible lies in a person's
>   determination.

You can translate it to this:

> Der Unterschied zwischen dem Unmöglichen und dem Möglichen liegt in
>   der Entschlossenheit einer Person.

or maybe this:

> Der Unterschied zwischen dem Unmöglichen und dem Möglichen liegt in
>   der Festlegung des Einzelnen.

What would you say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice work, apart from your first translation I'd go for

> Der Unterschied zwischen dem Unmöglichen und dem Möglichen liegt in der Entschlossenheit des Einzelnen.

although that is obviously not gendered, so if that's required:

> Der Unterschied zwischen dem Unmöglichen und dem Möglichen liegt in der Entschlossenheit der jeweiligen Person.

Comment: [Just in case.](http://www.dict.cc/?s=jeweilig)

Comment: +1 I like the first one. It sounds "natural" and keeps the reference to an individual.

Comment: Thanks. But would you say that "determination" can only mean "willpower" in this case or could it also mean "everyone has his own reality and thinks some things are possible and some not" -> Festlegung ?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the *only* interpretation, but I certainly saw the aspect of willpower first.

Answer (score 5):

Rather the first one. I would allow a bit more freedom and say it this way:

> Ob etwas möglich oder unmöglich ist, ist eine Frage der Entschlossenheit.